Is FATCA mostly for other countries to report to the USA?
I have read the FATCA agreement for my country:
https://home.treasury.gov/system/files/131/FATCA-Agreement-Bulgaria-12-5-2014.pdf
I noticed things like the following passage and similar:

It seems to me that this contract only requires Bulgaria to share data about US taxpayers with the US, but not the other way around? I also read some articles about the EU criticizing the lack of reprocity.
Does FATCA enable or force the US to share more data about Bulgarias citizens, who have accounts or assets in the US, then before this agreement or is it truly 100% one sided?
What is the frequently mentioned thershhold of 50.000 mean?

FATCA is a US law, it has nothing to do with Bulgary or Bulgarians. FATCA requires certain reports from certain financial institutions about certain customers. In many countries such reports by a financial institution to a third party (which the US in this case is) are forbidden. As such, the US enters into agreements with these countries to allow their financial institutions to make such reports. The agreement is what matters to Bulgarians, since that agreement affects the local laws.
What the Bulgarian government negotiated with the US in return to allowing the financial institutions making such reports is entirely up to the Bulgarian government and has nothing to do with FATCA. Usually, however, these agreements do have a certain degree of reciprocity.
To figure out what your legal responsibilities are in Bulgaria you should talk to a lawyer licensed to practice law in Bulgaria, similarly for the US - talk to a US-licensed attorney.

I have read a lot of accounts of Americans with dealings in the EU, having headaches because of FATCA and am wondering if is also true the other way around to a degree.

@user1721135 I'm not aware of any particular onerous requirements the EU has that would be similar to FATCA. There are however various agreements on information sharing for money laundering and tax evasion prevention purposes which may be more behind the scenes.

@user1721135 The leverage the US uses to gather this information, is effectively the power to deny those foreign financial institutions from dealing in USD. Europe collectively may have some amount of leverage over use banks who would want to deal in Euros, but not nearly as much as Bulgarian banks would want to deal in USD.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon So if an EU authority wants to get information from the US in regards to its citizens for taxes, they probably need to ask a specific question? I read somewhere, that EU countries can query all bank accounts of its citizens from the US. But its not an automatic data exchange.

EU is not a country and it doesn't have citizens.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_citizenship @littleadv

@AriBrodsky this concept is not a citizenship, you cannot be a EU citizen without being a citizen of a EU member state.
